# How to call simple expressions in a paper which do not need any proof?

Tags: notation

I am using an expression in a paper which doesnt need a proof at all such as
$$\sum_{i=k}^K\binom{K}{i}p^i(1-p)^{K-i}$$
is a decreasing function of $k$ and 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{K}{i}p^{K-i}(1-p)^i$$
is an increasing function of $k$. However I connot write it in the text. Because I refer to this property in a non trivial proposition.

Question: How should I put this thing in a format? should I call it as a *statement* or *definition* or *corollary*?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You may not need to make a clearly separated statement, unless it is something that you use a lot.  Simply saying, for example, "As $\sum \cdots$ is decreasing wrt $K$..." at the appropriate point(s) will probably suffice.  It you do refer to it quite often, either _Fact_ or _Observation_ would work.

Comment: It certainly is not a definition.

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche and Arthur Fischer thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the term *Remark*.